# Autosize and fit gridview columns

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

i have a user form that contain some textbox and a grid view. my grid view contain 5 columns, what i am trying to is to autofit the first 4 columns and make the last one fill the remaining space available. i tried setting my first 4 columns auto Displayed Cells, AllCells.. and the last one to fill it work fine if the containing data in the first 4 columns don't exceed the column width, once they exceed the last column go out of bound.
Result:
[image]

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: So far, are you only doing sizing by config/settings? If you have code to do any of this, we need to see it.

Comment: Try setting the `MinimumWidth` property for the last `Fill` column to prevent it from completely disappearing in the case you show.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make all the columns visible and you don't care about truncating the string with "...", just add this in the code (for example in the Load event of the form or in the Draw event of the GridView):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to have the cell string in its entirety, you could programmatically decrease the cell font, it is not exactly aesthetic but I leave you a code as an example (obviously it must be used together with the code I wrote above):

```
private void AdaptCellsToDataGrid()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            bool ContentTruncated = true;

            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[column.Index];

            cell.Style.Font = dataGridView1.Font;
            Font currentCellFont = cell.Style.Font;
            float currentFontSize = currentCellFont.Size;
            float reduce = 1; //start with only 1 size reduction

            while (ContentTruncated == true)
            {
                Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();

                //measuring the string lenght at drawing
                SizeF sizeF = graphics.MeasureString(cell.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font);
                float textLength = sizeF.Width;

                if (textLength > cell.Size.Width)
                {
                    if ((currentFontSize - reduce) > 5) //if value is bigger than 5 reduce else stop reducing
                    {
                        cell.Style.Font = new Font(currentCellFont.FontFamily, (currentFontSize - reduce), currentCellFont.Style);
                        reduce = reduce + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (textLength <= cell.Size.Width)
                {
                    ContentTruncated = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I have helped you in some way. :)